# How to integrate $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-numbers, contour-integration

What is the method of integrating the following:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}$$

I tried doing it via using partial fractions and deduce that:

$$\frac{\ln(x+1)}{2} - \frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{4} + \frac{\arctan(x)}{2} + C$$
However  I am unsure how to use the limits given in the question.

I suspect there is a way to do this using contour integration and this is probably the most straightforward method but I cannot see how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use $\frac{1}{2}\ln(x+1)-\frac{1}{4}\ln\left(x^2+1\right)=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)$, then take the limit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac12\log(x+1)-\frac14\log(x^2+1)&=\frac14 \log\left(\frac{x^2+2x+1}{x^2+1}\right)\\\\
&=\frac14 \log\left(1+\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\right)
\end{align}$$

And we have the estimates for $x>0$

$$0\le \log\left(1+\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\right)\le \frac{2x}{x^2+1}$$

Can you finish now?

---

---

**ALTERNATIVE APPROACH:**

Let $I$ be given by the integral $I=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}\,dx$.  We write the integral as the sum of integrals, the first from $0$ to $1$ and the second from $1$ to $\infty$.  The we enforce the substitution $x\mapsto 1/x$ in the second integral.  Proceeding we have

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}\,dx+\color{blue}{\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}\,dx}\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{\color{blue}{x\mapsto 1/x}}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}\,dx+\color{blue}{\int_1^0 \frac1{(1+1/x)(1+1/x^2)}\,\left(-\frac1{x^2}\right)\,dx}\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}\,dx+\color{blue}{\int_0^1 \frac{x}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}\,dx}\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac1{1+x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac\pi4
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

As you did, you found that

$$F(x)=\int_0^x\frac{dt}{(1+t)(1+t^2)}=$$

$$\frac{\ln(x+1)}{2}-\frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{4}+\frac{\arctan(x)}{2}$$
Now, you have to compute
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}F(x)=?$$
for this, write it as

$$F(x)=\frac 14\ln\Bigl(\frac{(x+1)^2}{x^2+1}\Bigr)+\frac{\arctan(x)}{2}$$

you will find $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: I believe that I already covered this ... and much more!

Comment: @MarkViola Not in your first answer.

Comment: Yes, I certainly did cover it.  The edited version added the alternative approach.

Comment: In this case, you can delete my answer. From mobile i cannot.

Comment: Users cannot delete other users' answers.